# Removing the last n characters of a string if they match certain characters

Tags: ruby

What is the most elegant way to remove any trailing '?' or '!' from a string? The string may have any combination of trailing '?' or '!' or none at all. I have the following (which works) but it seems ugly to me. Is there a more Ruby-way?

```
t = 'what are you doing?!'
last_char = t[-1]
while last_char == '!' or last_char == '?'
  t.chop!
  last_char = t[-1]
end
```

Comment: Modifying Mudasobwa's answer, `'what are !!you ?doing????!!!!'[/\A.*?(?=[?!]+\z)/]` is another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'what are you doing?!'.sub(/[?!]+\z/, '')
#⇒ "what are you doing"
```

`\z` in the regular expression is the marker of the string’s end.

Comment: @mrCarnivore excuse me?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are right. Your solution works! I’ll remove my comment to not confuse anybody.

Comment: Thank you. Why didn't I think of regex??

Comment: @mudasobwa: why do you use +? That means a ? or ! must be there at least once. Should not * be the correct qzantifier?

Comment: @mrCarnivore no, it should not. The whole substitution is to be applied if and only we need to substitute anything.

Comment: But the question was that the string could contain ? or ! In any combination _or none at all_.

Comment: Thinking about it + or * makes no difference in this case. No substitution is needed when no ? or ! are there...

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'what are ?! you doing?!'

i = str.rindex(/[^?!]/)
  #=> 20
i ? str[0..i] : ''
  # => "what are ?! you doing"

str = '?!?!'

i = str.rindex(/[^?!]/)
  #=> nil
i ? str[0..i] : ''
  # => ""
```

See [String#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-rindex).